# findViewById() not found id in nested layout?

Tags: android

My xml :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="240dp"
android:layout_height="320dp"
android:gravity="center" 
android:background="@drawable/borders"  
 >....<LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/arearight"         
        android:layout_above="@+id/areabotleft"
        android:layout_below="@id/txtDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        >
        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/img_sun"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/sun-icon"
            android:contentDescription="@string/shop"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            /> ......
```

i use findViewbyid find img_sun (ImageView) but it not find ?
LinearLayout nested in RelativeLayout.
 i should do ...get img_sun ?

Comment: show us your .java file as your xml file seems ok

Comment: Did you try building the project ignoring the errors given by eclipse? Eclipse has some problems refreshing the auto-generated R file in your project when you add something in your xml file. You sometimes need to build on your own when you change something on xml files.

Answer (score 0):

"i use findViewbyid find img_sun (ImageView) "  Well, that's certainly not the proper syntax...  It should look like this:

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_sun);
```

Comment: i try it but R.id not identified id img_sun. it see ids belong to Relativelayout(level 1), ids belong to Linearlayout (level 2) not identified

Answer (score 0):

1) Clean your project first

2) If you have multiple layouts for your current Activity, check if your Views are defined in all of them.

Answer (score 0):

check whether you have an import like 'yourpackagename.R' in your activity.If then try to remove it..Also do a thorough clean..